# Blackberry app compilation error

Tags: blackberry-webworks

Please can anybody help me..
I am compiling a blackberry html5 app and is given out this error though I have search for the error but I have been unable to locate it
the error code is(as shown in the command line)

> "out: I/O Error: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error = 2, The system cannot
>   find the file specified
>   error response - <"code":1 , "msg":"[ERROR]>  \t\tRAPC exception occurred"

This error occurred during compilation

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify that you have the 32-bit JDK installed and NOT the 64-bit?